# How to write jasmine unit test for an angularJS factory method without mocking it

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to unit test a factory method without mocking the actual method call. How can I do it?

Below is my factory and I need to test factory method without mocking it.

```
angular
    .module('core.app')
    .factory('storageService', storageService);

function storageService() {
    var service = {
        getItem: getItem
    };

    return service;

    function getItem(keyName) {
        var data = sessionStorage.getItem(keyName);
        return JSON.parse(data);
    }
};
```

Below is my spec.ts file. Not sure, where I am making mistake. When I run the test, I get error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined'

import 'jasmine';

import * as angular from 'angular';

import 'angular-mocks';

describe("reddit api service", function () {

```
var storageService: any;


beforeEach(function () {
    angular.module('app.core');
});

beforeEach(inject(function (_storageService_) {
    storageService = _storageService_;
}));

it('returns ranks', inject(function () {
    var res = storageService.getItem('sdfsdf');
    expect(res).toEqual(5);
}));
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
it('should parse json stored in session storage') {
  sessionStorage.setItem('key', '{"hello": "world"}');

  expect(storageService().getItem('key').hello).toBe('world');
}
```

Comment: Can we directly call factory like storageService()? I was looking at creating or injecting the instance of factory.

Comment: So your question is not how to test your service, but how to inject it in a test? See https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject

Comment: My ultimate goal is to test the service method. But I was curious that your suggested code directly calls the service using storageService(). Would it work without having an instance of the service? Also, both service and spec.ts files are in same folder. In this case do I need to load the module?

Comment: Because I couldn't remember how to inject a service in an AngularJS unit test, and your function seems to be defined as a global function anyway.

Comment: storageService().getItem('key').hello gave error 'can not find name storageService'